# AngularJS nested routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm working a fairly simple AngularJS project with some deep route nesting to select from a nested data structure:

```
angular.module('doccat', []).
 config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
         when('/',                    { templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html', controller: DocDetailCtrl }).
         when('/:p0',                 { templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html', controller: DocDetailCtrl }).
         when('/:p0/:p1',             { templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html', controller: DocDetailCtrl }).
         when('/:p0/:p1/:p2',         { templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html', controller: DocDetailCtrl }).
         when('/:p0/:p1/:p2/:p3',     { templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html', controller: DocDetailCtrl }).
         when('/:p0/:p1/:p2/:p3/:p4', { templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html', controller: DocDetailCtrl }).
         otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
 }]);

function DocDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
   var path = [];
   if ($routeParams.p0) path.push($routeParams.p0);
   if ($routeParams.p1) path.push($routeParams.p1);
   if ($routeParams.p2) path.push($routeParams.p2);
   if ($routeParams.p3) path.push($routeParams.p3);
   if ($routeParams.p4) path.push($routeParams.p4);

   // do stuff with  path
}
```

This has up to 5 layers in the path, which should be plenty for my purposes, so it is good enough for now. However, the underlying data *could* be nested arbitrarily deep, which would require arbitrary routing. 
I think the ideal for this would be a route that says 'all the rest of the path goes to any array of parameters', but it doesn't look like there is a way to do anything like that in AngularJS. Just for the sake of completeness, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check $routeProvider in the doc 
[angularjs $routeProvider](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24routeProvider).

Especially, in the definition of 'when', you can read: "path can contain named groups starting with a star (*name). All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches." So you just need to make sure the route matches and you'll get plenty parameters stored in $routeParams.

I hope it helps.